# Deeplearning4j repeated method calls

Tags: deeplearning4j

In many (or most) Deeplearning4j example I have seen, when building a configuration method calls seem to be added to method calls . . .

For example:

```
 MultiLayerConfiguration conf = new NeuralNetConfiguration.Builder()
            .seed(rngSeed) //include a random seed for reproducibility
            // use stochastic gradient descent as an optimization algorithm
            .updater(new Nesterovs(0.006, 0.9))
            .l2(1e-4)
            .list()
            .layer(0, new DenseLayer.Builder() //create the first, input layer with xavier initialization
                    .nIn(numRows * numColumns)
                    .nOut(1000)
                    .activation(Activation.RELU)
                    .weightInit(WeightInit.XAVIER)
                    .build())
            .layer(1, new OutputLayer.Builder(LossFunction.NEGATIVELOGLIKELIHOOD) //create hidden layer
                    .nIn(1000)
                    .nOut(outputNum)
                    .activation(Activation.SOFTMAX)
                    .weightInit(WeightInit.XAVIER)
                    .build())
            .pretrain(false).backprop(true) //use backpropagation to adjust weights
```

.build();

Occassionally I see examples where thh conf variable is created in one statement, and then each of the other operations are created in separate statements.  **Is there any benefit in doing it the first way?**  It does tend to obfuscate when a particular method call returns a different type of object.  Also, it would seem that the second approach would be more amenable to working with Jshell.

Comment: Both are usable.  You'll see the multi-statement configuration used a lot in networks like ResNet where you want to have a loop that adds the layers.

Answer (score 0):

It's up to you really. For some folks the builder syntax (it's java people, remember that before commenting) - is verbose and wrapping it makes it easier.
If you can make use case specific assumptions, then a method makes more sense.